# Exception in Tkinter callback using SHAP

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, shap

I'm trying to draw some [SHAP plots](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) in Python to gain a deeper understanding of the output of my machine learning models. This is the method I'm calling in a for loop:

```
def plotAndSaveSHAPSummary(model,train_data,x_train,pathToSHAPPlots):
    shap_values = model.get_feature_importance(train_data, type='ShapValues')
    expected_value = shap_values[0,-1]
    shap_values = shap_values[:,:-1]

    shap.summary_plot(shap_values,x_train,max_display=20,show=False)
    plt.savefig(pathToSHAPPlots+'/SHAP Plots/SHAP_Plot'+str(counter)+'.png',dpi=300,bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.clf()
```

The plots are saved to the disk as expected but after each call of the savefig method, I get the following error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PathTo\Anaconda\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\PathTo\Anaconda\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 749, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "D:\PathTo\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 270, in idle_draw
    self.draw()
  File "D:\PathTo\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 9, in draw
    super(FigureCanvasTkAgg, self).draw()
  File "D:\PathTo\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 393, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "D:\PathTo\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1535, in _draw
    def _draw(renderer): raise Done(renderer)
matplotlib.backend_bases._get_renderer.<locals>.Done: <matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.RendererAgg object at 0x000002066B288288>
```

Any ideas how to get rid of this exception?

Comment: I ran into the same error recently using just matplotlib and resolved it (hackily) by adding a small plt.pause(1e-13) just before the savefig call.   I don't know why this works, but assume there is a race condition somewhere in the matplotlib code.

Answer (score 4):

I started getting this error too after update of one of the libs, probably matplot lib. The suggestion to use `plt.pause` described in the comment worked but it is internally calling `plt.show()` which was unacceptable for me. I ended up adding `canvas.start_event_loop` just before the `savefig`

```
import sys

def _save(self, filename: str) -> None:
   fig1 = plt.gcf()
   fig1.set_size_inches(6, 2.8)
   plt.draw()
   fig1.subplots_adjust(left=0.20)
   fig1.canvas.start_event_loop(sys.float_info.min) #workaround for Exception in Tkinter callback
   fig1.savefig(self.dst_dir + '/' + filename + '.png', dpi=220, bbox_inches='tight')
   fig1.clf()
   plt.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
plt.ioff()
```

did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I have a simple script in Python to make a chart that used to work fine, but now when it tries to save the file, that exact warning shows. I spent a lot of time trying to figure out what was happening, since the error was sudden and the message is not very informative.

I found out that it disappears when I omit the `bbox_inches` parameter at `savefig`.

I noticed the error started happening after I installed `python-tk`, but uninstalling it does not help.

[Mariu's answer] `plt.ioff()` doesn't work for me.

[nan's answer] `fig1.canvas.start_event_loop(sys.float_info.min)` does work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem when saving multiple plots with matplot lib. Adding plt.close() after saving the figure worked for me.